# Google Play open beta testing: app not available

Tags: android

I would like to know why I get "App not available" page when I go to the opt-in URL on an Android device. When I go to the link on a computer, it works.

I have tried with the same account on both computer and phone. The app is published and beta testing is active. On a computer, I can opt in using the opt-in link. But it's only on the phone that I can't. The app supports the device and its API version.

Any suggestions?

**Update**

I have tried with some other devices using Android 5, and Android 6, and they worked. The phone I am having trouble with is using Android 4. But I don't think the API version is the problem because my app supports Android 4.

Comment: @Mike As mentioned in the question, I am signed in with the same account on both computer and phone.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. On a computer I could opt in using the opt-in link but not on the tablet.

The problem for me was the letters case as I was typing the address manually.

for example:
https://play.google.com/apps/testing/com.companyname.AppNameX  (working)

I was typing:
https://play.google.com/apps/testing/com.companyname.appnamex  (not working)

It turns out that the page address is case sensitive...
(always thought URLs where case insensitive, I guess only the DNS part maybe... :-)